# In Grafana, how do I use a variable I made and give it as a value into a query search for a graph?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I am trying to take the value of a drop down I created in grafana, utilizing a query variable.
I am using SimpleJSON for my database.

I have tried this pattern where:
**var** is my variable that makes up the drop down menu
*func* is my function call for the database query that creates the graph

So then I wrote:
f.g.*func*[$**var**]

I get a Internal Server Error yet when I call *func* in kdb+ with the values directly, it works fine. So I think I'm passing in **var** incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grafana/kdb+ adaptor, the syntax is f.g.*func*["$**var**"]-- my above attempt lacks the quotes necessary